# drupal 6 /user/permissions checkbox page core module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Does anyone know where i can find the code that makes the user/permissions checkbox page in drupal? I'd like to see how it's done to make something similar for a custom module i'm building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `theme_checkbox($element)` and can be found in `root/includes/form.inc`. If you ever want to know what function/template is responsible for a certain HTML element then [**Theme developer**](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is your friend.

Enable the module, set the permissions and you'll see a small checkbox *Themer info*. Then just point to the HTML part you're interested and see what theme function/template is doing the rendering.

Comment: so if i want to create a form that uses the theme_checkboxes($element) function  I can just call it specifically?

Comment: what is <span id="thmr_803" class="thmr_call"> page_example</span> module?

Comment: forms obviously are using their own elements themes but if i want to change it, i need to define a new #type?

Comment: once you enable the theme developer module it adds those ` <span id="thmr_803" class="thmr_call">` elements. But once you disable it everything is back to normal. You should always disable Theme developer once you're done using it, because it can break you're styling.

Comment: yes i see. What is thmr_803 or for that matter, any of the other arbitrary numbers?

Comment: He wraps the HTML elements in spans with custom IDs so he knows which part of the HTML chunk you're hovering and what information should display. I wouldn't worry about it too much. More important to know what/when to use the module, rather than it's internals.

Answer (score 0):

i think on default module folder there is user folder on user.admin.inc file contain code for permission function is user_admin_perm(); see this code